# Equations of motion of particle mass on parabolic surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, coriolis-effect

Given a parabolic surface
$$ Z = \frac{\Omega^2}{2g}\left(X^2 + Y^2\right)$$
My textbook (Introduction to Geophysical Fluid Dynamics, 2nd ed, p.50) states: "Provided that the paraboloid is sufficiently flat compared to its radius $R$ ($\Omega^2R/2g \ll 1$), the equations of motions of the mass are easily derived
$$ \frac{d^2X}{dt^2} = -g \frac{\partial Z}{\partial X}, \quad \frac{d^2Y}{dt^2} = -g \frac{\partial Z}{\partial Y}$$
Firstly, how can this be shown? Secondly, why is it important for the paraboloid to be sufficiently flat?

Comment: Generally when you see the phrase "sufficiently flat" it means that a Taylor linearization step will be needed to get to the suggested answer. Look at the derivation of the constant period of a pendulum for such an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatness here means that the vertical component of motion can be neglected, i.e., $Z \ll R$ where $R=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the horizontal displacement. To derive the equations of motion (without using the Lagrangian or Hamiltonian formalism which would be the most direct method here) just write down the total energy  $E = mgZ +  m/2 \; (\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2) = m/2 \; \Omega^2 (x^2+y^2)+  m/2 \; (\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)$. This can be viewed as total energy of two independent particles, one moving in the x direction, the other in y. For each of these, say the x particle, the total energy is $E = m/2 \; \Omega^2 x^2+  m/2  \; \dot{x}^2 $ which can be recognized as energy of a simple harmonic oscillator, and from $dE/dt=0$ we find the familiar equation of motion, $\ddot{x} = - \Omega^2 x$. Next, from given Z(x,y) we find $g \partial_x{Z}=\Omega^2 x$ to arrive finally at $\ddot{x} = -g \; \partial{Z}/\partial{x}$. Similarly for the y component, $\ddot{y} = -g \; \partial{Z}/\partial{y}$.